# Registered signal and Fmax in Timing Analyzer from Quartus II

Tags: verilog, shift-register, quartus, timing-analysis

I have the following module that is a simple register:

```
module linear_out
(
    input clock,
    input resetn,
    input [31:0] x,
    output reg [31:0] y
);

    always @(posedge clock)
        if (!resetn)
            y <= 32'h00000000;
        else
            y <= x;

endmodule
```

When I synthetize it with Quartus II and I check the *fmax* in *Timing Analyzer from Quartus II*, the *fmax* advice that: *No paths to report*, but the output is registered... If instead of set only one register, I set two, the *fmax* already shows a value.

But, I don't get it: Why is it? Is it neccesary set 2 or more clock cycles to get a syntetyzable design with a *known fmax*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't a shift register, it's just a register. The only flip-flops are the 32 that implement the register `y`, and all of their inputs and outputs go directly to I/O pins. Since there are no paths that go from one flip-flop to another, the timing analyzer can't compute the minimum time required for a clock period.

If your module had a mode in which it computed, say, `y <= {y[30:0], x[0]};`, then you'd have a shift register, and such paths would exist, allowing the computation of the minimum clock period and the corresponding \$F_{max}\$.

Answer (score 0):

\$f_{max}\$ is limited by the length of chained lookup tables between elements (typically registers) that use the same clock.

You only have 32 parallel paths with a single lookup table and register each, and the I/O primitives you use are not clocked themselves, so there is no path between two clocked elements to be analyzed. The distance from the pin through the lookup table to the register can be seen in the setup/hold time requirements for the input pins, but don't affect \$f_{max}\$ at all.

You could force clocked I/O primitives e.g. by using ALTDDIO_IN and ALTDDIO_OUT, these are basically registers integrated into the I/O pins.